# Required Permissions C# Attribute doesn't appear to work with bitwise or

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, bit-manipulation, bitflags

```
// [RequiredPermission(Permissions.ProjectManagement | Permissions.UserManagement)] //doesn't work
// [RequiredPermission(Permissions.UserManagement)] //works
[RequiredPermission(Permissions.ProjectManagement)] //works
public ActionResult Index() {}
```

Working with the attribute for the method above I can't seem to get the bitwise or to work.  I thought the or would work here can anyone explain why it doesn't?

Because this works: [RequiredPermission(Permissions.UserManagement)]

This works: [RequiredPermission(Permissions.ProjectManagement)]

But this doesn't: [RequiredPermission(Permissions.ProjectManagement | Permissions.UserManagement)]

It doesn't throw any exceptions?

Here are our flags:

```
[Flags]
    public enum Permissions : int
    {
        None = 0x0,
        Recruiting = 0x1,
        ProjectManagement = 0x2,
        UserManagement = 0x4,
        SystemManagement = 0x8,
    }
```

Is there an alternative way to do this?

I am trying to require either permission to enter.
It doesn't work meaning that It wont let the ProjectManagement user in when using them together. Like [RequiredPermission(Permissions.ProjectManagement | Permissions.UserManagement)]. No exceptions are thrown.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "works" in the first place. Are you trying to require *both* permissions or *either* of them?

Comment: sorry edited i am trying to require either permission to enter

Comment: And what behaviour are you seeing? (Again, you've only said it "doesn't work" rather than the exact symptoms.)

Comment: You need to use bitwise logic to check if a flag is set. `bool HasPermission(Permissions actual, Permissions value) { return (actual & value) == value; }`